# Jenkins rebuild Test Result Trend

Tags: jenkins

I just have deleted old build files from disk and did a "Reload Configuration from Disk", but in the "Test Result Trend" the old builds are still visible.

I've also restarted Jenkins - same result.

How can I rebuild Test Result Trend to show only statistics of builds existing on disk?

I'm running Jenkins 2.73.1 on Windows7.

Tia Udo

Comment: After a day, the problem has disappeared. Maybe Jenkins needs some time to refresh the Test Result Trend.

Comment: It looks to me like deleting a build interferes with the Test Result Trend graph.